# Feature requests get tumbleweeded?

Tags: feature-request, support, chat

A while back...on travel.SE, [we requested that Wikitravel posts get expanded in chat](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/396/101).  This was done amazingly fast, and everyone was happy.

Then a dark event took place in the travel wiki world, and Wikivoyage split off from Wikitravel.  The new, nicer Wikivoyage is now what most of us try to use.

However, we don't get it expanding in chat.

So we raised another request to get [Wikivoyage posts expanded in chat](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1213/101).

However, that was **7 months ago now**.  Is there some process by which this got declined, and we can't see, or is it just languishing, or skipped over, or what?

Comment: 6 to 8 weeks is industry-standard, but 6 to 8 *months*?

Comment: The dark event was WikiTravel becoming more evil. The split was the wonderful event that occurred as a result.

Comment: Just get a moderator to pass the question along to a Community Manager; they'll look at it. No need to ask new questions about it here on MSO...

Comment: Could it be that questions on the per-site metas just don't get very much attention from the Stack Exchange staff? I know I've been told a few times that they monitor them all, but evidence seems to suggest otherwise. (And not just this evidence.)

Comment: @animuson: Is that something we do via flagging? I can't recall hearing of this feature/technique before. Where can we read more about it please?

Comment: @hippietrail I wouldn't recommend flagging. If you can't find a moderator in the question itself or a chat room, you can always head to the [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta) here on Meta and pass it along to a CM directly. They hang out there often, and are pretty good at getting back to you. Don't be impatient and only wait a week after you asked something, though.

Comment: Aha thanks for that. This particular one hasn't been a week old for six months and three weeks though (-;

Answer (score 7):

A large number of feature requests don't get an offical answer from SE. If the feature request didn't receive many upvotes, or was even downvoted heavily, it might just have been a bad idea, or just not a good enough idea to be implemented.

In all other cases it is rather hard to determine why it wasn't implemented without specific feedback. It might be because nobody from SE that can do anything about it saw it, or that it was considered too much effort to implement for not enough gain.

As a regular user I usually try to rethink an old feature request when it doesn't get enough attention, and edit it to address any points that I could think of in the meantime. If I don't have anything to improve, I sometimes just add a bounty, though that doesn't really do much on MSO. But it might get the community to look at it and find some problems or express their support for it.

As a moderator there is a much easier way, we can just ping an SE employee in TL and remind them about a feature request that is important for our site. Annoying the comm team about bugs or features relevant to your site is in the moderator job description, and it is very useful for stuff that just got lost on the way and to communicate issues that are specifically important to your site. So you can ask one of your mods to remind SE about the feature.

Comment: Use the hierarchy guys! Regular users can gently hassle site mods to gently hassle an SE employee / Community Manager (-:

Comment: @Mad - that's all well and good for a complicated feature. But this had been done before for Wikitravel, we just want the same thing for Wikivoyage.  There's really not much one can 'improve' about the question, it's fairly simple :/  But thanks, we'll bug...err, request the mods ping someone ;)

Answer (score 3):

Things that the SE team has seen and specifically decided NOT to implement will typically have the status-declined tag. (I won't say "always" because, well, we're human and we forget to edit tags sometimes.) Because we have 108 sites and only a couple dozen employees working with those sites, there are a lot of requests that we just don't get to.

Especially for the past few months, our devs have been working on several really large projects and don't have as much time to go spelunking for feature requests. (They *do* generally monitor bugs, though.) We certainly don't want little incremental improvements to get lost in the shuffle of bigger, more resource-intensive projects, so the community managers (and I) try to keep an eye out for features we think are a good idea, supported by the community, and won't take too much time to implement. We try to pass a few of these along per week to the developers, but like I said before, sometimes we just miss things.

I saw that Marc did implement your feature request; mods will often ping the community team for small changes, but your best bet is still posting on your site's meta. Sometimes things will fall through the cracks, in which case you can try poking an employee on a related message (as you did with Marc), posting here, or editing your feature request to bump it back to the "recently active" list.

Basically, if it doesn't actually have a status-declined tag on it, you should interpret that as we either didn't see it, didn't have time to make an informed decision about it, or think it's a good idea but don't have time for it right now. (That last group *should* make use of the status-deferred or status-planned tags, but again, we're not always great at keeping the tags up-to-date. If it's planned, there will usually be an answer or comment saying as much, though.)

We're doing the best we can; thanks for bearing with us. :)

Comment: Thanks Laura, good news, as you said - it *was* simply overlooked, and [Marc helped out with implementing it](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/1213/101) :)  All works well now! :D